# Cannot establish one-to-many relationship in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, one-to-many, cardinality

I have currently two tables in my Power BI model:

Clients and Client Visits

Both are imports from an SQL server.

I unduplicated the "Clients Table" to eliminate erroneous double entries.

When I try to establish a one-to-many relation based on social security numbers I get the following message:

"The cardinality you selected isn't valid for this relationship".

BTW, I set the "Cross filter direction" as: "Single (Clients Table filters Client Visits)".

Any advice as to how to solve this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Drop the social security numbers from "Clients" into a table visual, and create a simple measure to count them. See if you get any numbers > 1

Comment: Do you mean < 1 ?

Comment: So my unduplication at the beginning may not have worked?

= Table.Distinct(#"Removed Duplicates", {"SSN"})

Comment: I have lots of missing SSN's... I am not sure hower PI deals with them.

Comment: There you go. These missing SSNs are counted as duplicates.

Comment: I have this now: 

= Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Duplicates1", each [SSN] <> null and [SSN] <> "")

However, it still does not work...

Comment: Can you describe your Clients table? Better yet, a data sample would be great (just blind the SSNs).

Comment: ID_Table_Clients Entry_Date R_Number Last_Name First_Name Middle_Name Suffix Gender SSN DOB P_no U_NO MU_no Phone_Number
19601 12/9/2019 14:43 100074131 LN0001 FN0001 MN0001 NULL 1 99999001 1/1/1930 P0001 583210 NULL 9999990001
19602 12/9/2019 16:13 100074291 LN0002 FN0002 MN0002 NULL 1 99999001 1/2/1930 P0002 NULL NULL 9999990001
19603 12/10/2019 11:17 100084337 LN0003 FN0003 MN0003 NULL 2 99999001 1/3/1930 P0003 NULL NULL 9999990001
19604 12/10/2019 11:23 100001360 LN0004 FN0004 MN0004 NULL 1 99999001 1/4/1930 P0004 NULL NULL 9999990001

Comment: It's obvious that deduplication did not work. To find out why, run the test I suggested at the beginning, identify SSNs that have duplicates, and then investigate these records. There might be subtle issues like trailing spaces or hidden characters (i.e, see here https://radacad.com/remove-duplicate-doesnt-work-in-power-query-for-power-bi-here-is-the-solution)